# jquery popup time delay

Tags: jquery, popup

My This following script open popup box when page load . all Working fine But it loading immediately when page loading . i need add time delay function i want open popup after 5 seconds

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    overlay.show();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    $('.popup').show();
    $('.close').click(function() {
      $('.popup').hide();
      overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
      return false;

    });


    $('.x').click(function() {
      $('.popup').hide();
      overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
      return false;
    });

  });
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the setTimeOut function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ /** do what you want after 3 seconds */ }, 3000);
```

In your case you can use it like this:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ /** do what you want after 3 seconds */ }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: where the comments are in the above example place there your code starting with the line: var overlay =...

Answer (score 1):

the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function is an option:

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Here your code"); }, 3000);
```

Comment: How can i use this in my Code?